# Zero-sum stochastic games

Tags: game-theory

I'm studying zero-sum stochastic games for my dissertation and I came across this example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231786753_A_real-world_stochastic_two-person_game

> Consider a television game show where two contestants have to play a
> dice game. The contestants sit behind a battery of buttons numbered
> 1,2,...,D, which represent the numbers of the dice that will be thrown
> by the contestant. In each stage of the game the players press
> simultaneously one of the buttons; in particular, they cannot observe
> the other opponent's decision. Afterwards, they throw their dice,
> which score is dictated as it follows:
>
> - the score is equal to the sum of the outcome of the dice, if none of them showed 1 as outcome;
> - the score is null if at least one of the dice showed the outcome 1;
>   In any case, the result is added to their current total. The first
>   player who reaches a total of G points is the winner. If the players
>   reach the goal at them same turn, then the winner is the one with a
>   higher overall score. In case of a tie, the winner is determined by a
>   toss of a fair coin. At each stage both contestants have full
>   information about their own and the opponent's current total score.
>   The formulation of the game is such that it is zero-sum and
>   stochastic.

I get that it's stochastic but why is it zero-sum? From what I understand, since a stochastic game is a set of normal form games, in order for it to be zero-sum, all games of the set must be zero-sum.
However in the example the sum of the payoffs of the two players in general is not zero, since that happens only when both players had 1 in at least one of their dice.
What am i doing wrong in my reasoning? Can someone help me clarify this doubt?